# Javascript Error: Highchart Legend Tooltip Error on Doubling Up Charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a single chart webpage showing Highchart line:bar graph: http://www.jcsweb.biz/mef/AnimGIF/legend_csv_03h_1Cht_01d.htm

with external chart data: 
http://www.jcsweb.biz/mef/csv_dump/HC_TEST_DATA1.CSV

and Chart Legend Tooltip (long string) from an external file: http://www.jcsweb.biz/mef/csv_dump/HC_TEST_LEGEND1.CSV

So on mouseover of chart series legend, a much longer Legend tooltip is displayed (ie as held in HC_TEST_LEGEND?.CSV).

It all works fine, but hits problems with the longer Legend tooltip when I try and "double up" to display 2 (or more) such charts on a single webpage. http://www.jcsweb.biz/mef/AnimGIF/legend_csv_03h_2Cht_01d.htm

The Upper chart long Legend tooltip displays fine (as above) but the Bottom chart doesnt display ANY longer Legend description from HC_TEST_LEGEND2.CSV. 
In moving to 2 charts, I have tried to make the JavaScript code/variables names distinctive to each chart eg "legendData1" vs "legendData2" but I have run out of browser debug pointers to find the js coding legend tooltip error ! 
Any help/pointers on finding the offending code in Chart 2 much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is probably the value of `e2.clientY`. I debugged your code and it has the value higher than the chart's height. It seems that this value is relative to the whole document. When you assign attributes to your legend tooltip object then (`.attr()`) all the values are relative to the chart container. So in this case your tooltip is created outside of the chart and is not visible.

Here's **live working demo** of legend tooltip that uses properties of **SVGElements** instead of mouse event: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mujn4eja/